# Selenium webdriver chrome on Google App Engine

Tags: python, selenium, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver

I could find a lot of similar topics but none of them helped ...
I have installed chromedriver successfully on GAE but I keep getting the following.

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
start (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:83)
```

My python code.

```
try:
    if 'linux' in sys.platform:
        print("Headless Chrome Initialized on Linux")
        return webdriver.Chrome()
except WebDriverException as e:
    print(getattr(e, 'message', repr(e)))
    print(getattr(e, 'message', str(e)))
```

I can launch chromedriver from command line from server ...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Also tried with executable path /usr/bin/chromedriver but same result ...

```
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using the Python 3.7 runtime?

Comment: Yep but I spent some time investigating the issue and it looks like it is very much a nightmare to install remotely everything I wanted so I am now looking at scrapy/splash and scrapinghub :)

Comment: what version is your Chrome browser?

Comment: 77 in line with chromedriver!

Comment: Have you tried placing the executable in the same directory as your python file and webdriver.Chrome() with no parameters?

Comment: I think to be fair it is related to the way GAE is setup. I actually dont have access to the source code ... I can only deploy from my pc and then install stuff but the restrictions do not let me me fix the issue. I'll use it on my local pc for now.